# How to copy specified files whitout folder structure using overlays?

Tags: maven-2, overlay, war

I would like copy just "file.xml" without folder structure using overlays like this:

```
    <overlays>
     <overlay>
      <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>my_comp</artifactId>
      <includes>
        <include>WEB-INF/folder1/folder2/file.xml</include>
      </includes>
      <targetPath>WEB-INF/otherFolder</targetPath>
      <type>war</type>
    </overlay>
   </overlays>
```

In other words: copy **file.xml** from *WEB-INF/folder1/folder2/* and place to the *WEB-INF/otherFolder*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible with overlays, the content of the overlay is added "as is" to the targetPath (that defaults to the root structure of the webapp).

If you want to make **file.xml** available at another location, you'll have to tweak its location in `my_comp` WAR *before the overlay*.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find how to resolve the issue via overlays. So I had to use two plugins **maven-dependency-plugin** and **maven-war-plugin**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my_comp</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>WEB-INF/folder1/folder2/file.xml</includes>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
        <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                  <directory>${project.build.directory}/tmp/WEB-INF/folder1/folder2</directory>
                  <targetPath>WEB-INF/otherFolder</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The first plugin attached to the **process-resources** phase. The second invoked on phase **package** when all overlays combined. *Overlays are applied with a first-win strategy (hence if a file has been copied by an overlay, it won't be copied anymore)* If I've copy my file.xml (via plugin) then it not be overwritten by any overlay.

It's so complicated!